# JList - Highlight specific cells in red

Tags: java, swing, rendering, cell, jlist

I have a JList on a form. When the form loads, the JList is populated with items from my array. The items are products and have a "quantity in stock" number next to the product details. 
In the code below I find the stock number and if it is less than 5 I want that line to be highlighted in red.

At the moment my WHOLE Jlist is being highlighted in red if there is any quantity which is less than 5. Help!! 
I'm pretty new to Java so please explain as simply as possible!
If someone could explain *why* my code isn't working properly as well that would be great - I really don't understand quite a lot of the "Cell Rendering" stuff - I only came across it yesterday.

```
public void lowStock(){
    DefaultListModel<String> list = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    list = (DefaultListModel) lstProducts.getModel();
    int listSize = list.getSize();

    for (int i=0; i<listSize; i++){
        String element = list.get(i);
        int blankSpace = element.lastIndexOf("  ");
        String quantity = element.substring(blankSpace).trim();
        final int intQuantity = Integer.parseInt(quantity);

        if (intQuantity < 5){
            ListCellRenderer lstclrnd;
            lstProducts.setCellRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer(){  

            //element.setBackGround(Color.red);
        });
    }
}

class MyListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer  
{  
    private HashMap theChosen = new HashMap();  

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,  
            Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,  
            boolean cellHasFocus)  
    {  
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index,  
                isSelected, cellHasFocus );  

            theChosen.put( value, "chosen" );  
            setBackground( Color.red ); 
           if( theChosen.containsKey( value ) )  
        {  
            setBackground( Color.red );  
        }
```

Comment: When do you set the background to something other than red?

Comment: If there are less than 5 in stock the background should be red. If there are 5 or more in stock the background should not be red.

Comment: Okay, but when do you actually set the background to anything other than red? Looks to me like you're setting it to red no matter what.

Comment: No, red should be the only colour that is ever set. I really don't understand the code - I've never used a HashMap or a CellRenderer before

Comment: You need to set the color to something other than red for the color to be something other than red. Seriously, just change the first red to a blue to see what I mean.

Comment: HashMap haven't indexing, use another array

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in the following piece of code:

```
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,  
        Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,  
        boolean cellHasFocus)  {  

    super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);  

    theChosen.put(value, "chosen");  
    setBackground( Color.red ); //MOST LIKELY THIS LINE RIGHT HERE
    if( theChosen.containsKey( value )) {  
        setBackground( Color.red );  
    }
    ...
```

Without that line `setBackground( Color.red );`, no color should be set.

It is kind of hard to see exactly what is going on- you should submit an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/). This is just a couple of code snippets.

Honestly, I think what you are trying to do is set a `ListCellRenderer` for your `JList`. Something like the following should suffice.

```
 class MyCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer<Object> {
     public MyCellRenderer() {
         setOpaque(true);
     }

     public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list,
                                                   Object value,
                                                   int index,
                                                   boolean isSelected,
                                                   boolean cellHasFocus) {

         //I don't know why you would have leading whitespace here... but w/e
         //This probably needs modification depending on your data
         String quantity = value.toString().substring(blankSpace).trim();
         setText(quantity);
         int intQuantity = Integer.parseInt(quantity);

         Color background;
         Color foreground;

         if (intQuantity < 5) {
             background = Color.RED;
             foreground = Color.WHITE;

         } else {
             background = Color.WHITE;
             foreground = Color.BLACK;
         }

         setBackground(background);
         setForeground(foreground);

         return this;
     }
 }
```

Then, your `JList`, probably right after you initialize it, needs to do the following:

```
myJList.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do way to much. You don't need the `Map` at all. See below, very simple.

The reason you currently getting all colored red is because you have `setBackground` outside of the `if`. So no matter what happens, it will be red. You can see more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) on how to use a render for a list

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ListColorRed {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Integer[] nums = {10, 2, 5, 8, 2, 9, 2, 8, 10, 4, 6};
                JList list = new JList(nums);
                list.setCellRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {

                    @Override
                    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
                            Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
                            boolean cellHasFocus) {

                        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index,
                                isSelected, cellHasFocus);

                        Integer num = (Integer) value;

                        if (num < 5) {
                            setBackground(Color.RED);
                        }

                        return this;
                    }
                });

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(list));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]