# JComboBox Text Color (Red or Green)

Tags: java, swing, colors, jcombobox

These are the requirements for my JComboBox:

1) There is an array with 10 elements (DONE)

2) My JComboBox always has 9 elements (once an element is selected, that element is removed and the element that was not in the JComboBox is added) (DONE)

3) I need to set the color of each JComboBox item to either green or red (this will be determined on my own accord and will change once an element is selected (NEED HELP)

I am confused on how to create a JComboBox with either green or red colored items. The current solutions I've seen have an array color of length n and an array labels of length n. However, in this case, I want an array labels of length n and only two possible colors.

Essentially, I want a simple method that can set the color of the current index in JComboBox (something like this):

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
comboBox.addItem(x, Color.red);
comboBox.addItem(y, Color.green);
comboBox.addItem(z, Color.green);
```

Unfortunately, I do not have any code as I am not sure how to begin and have been using the default JComboBox Java provides.

Comment: The basic approach is using a custom cell renderer, as explained in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer . An example of such a renderer (extending `DefaultListCellRenderer`) is shown e.g. in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22181531/3182664 . Does this help?

Comment: This does help. However, whenever I try to integrate this with my current code, I get a JComboBox that no longer has a width or height (it is very small)

Comment: You just called `comboBox.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() { /* see other answer* /});` without changing anything else? That should work. In doubt, editing the question to show your current code could help. (I could write an answer, but hesitate to do so, because there already are *many* questions where the answer was some sort of cell renderer, but if necessary, I could write an answer tomorrow)